# I want to order id auto genarate and set text field, below function dosen't working. Is it correct?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, auto-generate

I want to order id auto genarate and set text field, below function dosen't working. Is it correct?

```
function generateOrderID() {
    try {
        let lastOrderId = orderDB[orderDB.length-1].getOrderId();
        let newOrderId = parseInt(lastOrderId.substring(1,7))+1;
        if (newOrderId < 10) {
            $("#txtOrderId").val('D00-00'+newOrderId);
        }else if (newOrderId < 100) {
            $("#txtOrderId").val('D00-0'+newOrderId);
        } else {
            $("#txtOrderId").val('D00-'+newOrderId);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        $("#txtOrderId").val("D00-001");
    }
}
```

Comment: `lastOrderId.substr(1,7)` will return following value for example `'D00-012' => '00-012'`, if this is parsed to an int, it will only look at the numbers until a char which can not be parsed appears, so it will parse `00` to an int and ignore `-012` (because `-` can not be parsed), so `parseInt` will always return `0` and  newOrderId will always be `1`

Comment: coul'd you please correct it code?